# Calculate the sum of all numbers in a memory block and the sum of all elements in an array

Tags: c, pointers

When compiling the program below, the terminal gives me the following message
"double free or corruption (out)". I want to create a program that first calculates the sum of all the elements in an array, see x below. Then I want
calculate the sum of all numbers in a memory block pointed to by a pointer, see y below. I believe that the problem lies in the assignment "y=x;"

```
int main(void)
{
    double x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    printf("The sum is %f\n", sum(x, 10));

    double *y = malloc(sizeof(double)*10);
    y = x;

    printf("The sum is %f\n", sum(y, 10));
    free(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The pointer `y` was never allocated by `malloc` (because you immediately overwrite and lose the return value of `malloc`).

Comment: you can't assign arrays in C, you can allocate memory for them, and then copy the values using `memcpy` though. What you have now is a leak: you're allocating `10 * sizeof *y` (unless `malloc` returns `NULL`), and then reassign `y` to point to `x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment `y = x` overwrites the `malloc()`ed pointer and you end up `free()`ing a stack variable<sup>1</sup> which is *undefined behavior*. And also, the `malloc()`ed pointer is never `free()`ed.

From your code, it seems that you don't need `malloc()` at all<sup>2</sup>. But if it's required then this might be what you need

```
double *y;
y = malloc(10 * sizeof(*y));
if (y == NULL)
    return -1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    y[i] = i + 1;
printf("The sum is %f\n", sum(y, 10));
free(y);
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You actually `free()` the address of `x`.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>You could just call `sum(x, 10)`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't use `free()` for what is not allocated via `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` (including functions that return pointers allocated via them, for example, `strdup()`). If you do so, it means you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.22.3.3 The free function:

> If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.

The `y = x;` line causes memory leak because it will erase the pointer to the buffer allocated and assign the address of (first element of) `x` to `y`.